# Did I interpret the question correctly? In correct English?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

On another question I asked, I realised the first sentence should read like the one below. Now I need to ask if it goes with my second sentence?

> Any play, literally or figuratively, is confined to a certain place
>   where the story unfolds. In this essay, I will discuss the nature of
>   Elsa’s character during her visit to Miss Helen within the confinement
>   of the time and space of the play.

This is the question I must answer: Based on the discussion of the **idea of confinement** in Chapter Four of Introduction to English Literary Studies (IELS), write an essay of at least five paragraphs in which you discuss how the **confinement of time and space** enables the audience or reader to see more deeply into the nature of Elsa’s character during her visit to Miss Helen. You must make references to relevant aspects of the play to support your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your interpretation seems correct, I would reword the second sentence to demonstrate the relation between the confinement of time and space, and the audience's perception of Miss Helen.

...will discuss the influence of the time and space confinements on the reader's potential interpretation of Elsa's character.

Hence, I believe, it is more clear you wish to show how this confinement affects character perception, rather than describe character perception within confinement.

Hope this helps :)